# How can I add setup goal to clover in Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a maven project, and I can run coverage on it on my own machine, no problem after following instructions here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/clover-for-maven-2-and-3-quick-start-guide-160399608.html

When I use Jenkins to run `clean clover:setup test clover:aggregate clover:clover`, it complains that it `Could not find goal 'setup' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clover-plugin:2.4 among available goals aggregate, check, instrumentInternal, instrument, log, clover, save-history`

Obviously there is no settings file on the Jenkins box. I'm not sure how it even knows those available goals offhand. And I'm not sure how to add that last goal.

I tried this to no avail:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.18</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

The second plugin is what I added, in the hopes to mirror what the settings.xml file was doing on my local machine.

I figure another option is to edit the settings file on Jenkins itself. That is probably the best one...

[image]

My Jenkins is in Docker so I just ran `docker exec -it abc /bin/bash` and got in. When I go to .m2 I don't see a settings.xml. So not sure what Jenkins is saying it's going to reference. I'm going to try out just putting `settings.xml` here and see how that goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made sure that it was using my global settings file, and made that file match what was on my machine. Didn't need to touch my `pom.xml` at all.